# ¿Cómo aplicar el principio Open Close de SOLID con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

utilizando el siguiente ejemplo de JS

```
function validadorCampo(){
var campos = ["idCampo1","idCampo2","idCampo3"];
      for(var i = 0;i<campos.length;i++ ){
        validarCampo(campos[i]);
      }
}

function validarCampo(idCampo){
//if null do some stuff to highlight field - just for illustrate
}
```

¿Como podría aplicar el principio **Open Close** de **SOLID**?
imaginen que tuviera que añadir mas campos a validar, bueno se me ocurre agregar esos campos dentro del arreglo de "campos", ¿Rompo con el principio cierto?, ahora en el ejemplo anterior el *"idCampo3"* solo debería ser validado en caso de que por ejemplo los campos *idCampo1* y *idCampo2* tengan información. ¿Como validar esas excepciones? (en el caso de que por ejemplo en el futuro se agregaran "n" campos y algunos campos dependan de otros para ser o no validados) 
 Saludos. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El principio demuestra que la base no debe ser cambiada para extender la funcionalidad. No puedes tener dos funciones con el mismo nombre, no son distintas, no es Java, la segunda sustituirá a la primera.

> imaginen que tuviera que añadir mas campos a validar, bueno se me ocurre agregar esos campos dentro del arreglo de "campos", ¿Rompo con el principio cierto?

Agregar más elementos al array no rompe ningún principio, aunque si son completamente estáticos, tampoco afectaría.

```
var campos = ["idCampo1","idCampo2","idCampo3"];
```

¿No deberían llegar por parámetros?

```
var campos = ["idCampo1","idCampo2","idCampo3"];
preValidar(campos);
function preValidar(campos){
// Aquí podrías agregar toda tu lógica.
      for(var i = 0;i<campos.length;i++ ){
        validarCampo(campos[i]);
      }
}

function validarCampo(idCampo){
// Aquí iría la función sin ninguna modificación.
}
```

El principio consiste en la abstracción de ideas, una función hace algo en concreto, puedes separarla hasta lograr reutilizar el código de una función en otras que son completamente distintas. aún podrías usar validarCampo en los campos, continuando el principio.

Comment: Una observación: las funciones en la pregunta no tienen el mismo nombre. Una se llama `validador...`  y la otra se llama `validar...`.

Comment: Ya me hacen faltan lentes, toda la razón @MauricioContreras